# Security groups and UDP on Heroku

Tags: networking, heroku

Has anyone experienced running multiple collaborating applications on Heroku? For example, an admin application to manage another application; or a stats server observing another application?

On Amazons' EC2 platform you can use security groups to restrict access to servers, creating a virtual network between your application or server instances. Is there any such way to do this on Heroku?  If so, can you open UDP as well as TCP connections?

Thanks

Robbie

Comment: As far as I know, there are no internal interfaces with Heroku, so you could not achieve this as you would with EC2 (or a VPS provider). You would need to establish an API for your applications and communicate over that (using HTTPS/TLS).

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @elithrar is correct. To talk between applications you either need to define an API, or used shared resources. For example you can have 2 applications connect to the same database by manually copying and pasting the DATABASE_URL from one app to another. This has the downside that should we need to roll credentials (very rare) your manually copied configuration will break.

The same pattern can be used with any add-ons, such as https://addons.heroku.com/redistogo or https://addons.heroku.com/iron_mq to share a message bus or queue between two applications.

Comment: Yeah, I had the suspicion that might be the only way. I was hoping someone might be able to point a way, so that I might be able to use something like statsd.